# Can't play music from FMODStudio in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, fmod

I created an audio project with FMOD studio, then I want to connect to a unity3d project. I've a first person charachter, and I added the FMOD Studio component to the FPSController, but no music comes out:
[image]

The intensity is not the volume, just a parameter to "mix" different ambientations.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found: Another component has to be added to the FPSCharacter itself: FMOD Studio listener. With this it works.